# Azure pipeline gulp yarn install fails authorization on private repo

Tags: azure-devops, gulp, yarnpkg

I moved some classic Yarn installs from the Azure pipelines into a gulpfile so that they can be installed in parallel. The issue is that when it tries to install the one module we have in a private repo (hosted also on Azure), the install fails with 401 unauthorized.

```
var yarn = require('gulp-yarn');

gulp.task("yarn-cms", () => {
  return gulp.src(['./src/MyProject/ClientApp/package.json'])
    .pipe(yarn());
});
```

I do have a `.npmrc` with the link to the registry and always-auth=true, but even if I change the link to the registry it seems like it instead insists on using the one in yarn.lock leading me to believe that `.npmrc` is being ignored, and hence that always-auth=true setting.